# Need to rasterize odd-sized SVG files for a thermal receipt printer in python

Tags: python, svg, printing, thermal-printer

Need to rasterize odd-sized SVG files for a thermal receipt printer in python.

I have a thermal printer is 384px across, and "unlimited" in length. I am currently generating SVG files that could easily be rendered (at 200px/in) to 73152 x 384 pixels (that's the full width of the printer, 30 feet long).

I've tried using cairosvg (aka svglib) and unsurprisingly get a CAIRO_STATUS_INVALID_SIZE memory error. I suspect that even if cairosvg could handle it, when I pass it to PIL to rasterize it, PIL would likely have problems also. I could render at a far lower resolution, but it quickly gets chunky when I scale up to 200px/in.

I've also looked around for other svg python modules, but nothing looks like they'd work.

It would be best if I "chunked" the input anyway because that's what the printer needs i.e., render 384x1024 chunks of the SVG file at a time with some kind of "window" that I could pan through the rendered SVG file... somehow.

Any ideas?

thx, tom.c

Comment: You may be running into an artificial limit at 65535 or 32767 pixels.

Comment: Or maybe just a memory problem, that's 28 megapixels after all.

Comment: Ya, 28 megapixels, "shrug". Now-a-days that's not that much.

Comment: I could iterate to find the artificial limit, but then what. I'll likely have to wrestle with PIL's artificial limits also. .. unless  the community here knows easy ways to increase these limits.

Comment: There is also svg.path that understands svg files, but I'd have to do the rasterizing myself. Gotta be a easier way!

Comment: I didn't pick those limits arbitrarily, they're the maximum numbers afforded by an unsigned and signed 16 bit integer.

Comment: What restrictions exist and what you have to do to deal with them depends on the printer specifications. Carefully examine the printer hardware specifications and print control command specifications. It will be difficult to get accurate advice and answers as you have not provided information on them or the printer vendor and model.

Comment: I believe I was pretty clear re: the printer specifications. The question is how to rasterize, not how to print (I already can print). As I said above, the printer is a thermal receipt printer that prints 384 pixels wide and 190 feet long (it's a roll). That would be 203.2 (pix/in) * 12 * 190 = 463296 pixels. Yes, I can print until I abort it.

Comment: Now that we know that the limits are not artificial, that strongly suggests that I will need to "chunk" the rasterization. I.e., rasterize 384x1024 print it, then do the next 1024 pixels.

Comment: For what it's worth, the printer is a TEROW T5890K Thermal Receipt Printer 58mm POS. It uses ESC/POS that's standard for most Receipt printers.

Comment: They are not enough information. This is because ESC/POS has different ranges and detailed parameters supported by various vendors and models. This is especially noticeable in the fields of image printing and barcode printing. Even within EPSON, different models support different content. So you need to know the exact hardware/software specifications of your printer. And if you ask an image or barcode printing question, you need to present it so that others can refer to it.

Comment: Again. I currently have code that allows me to print 10's of feet of graphics. The width is 384 pixels, and I haven't run into a printer limit on length. The printer's not the issue. The problem is parsing an SVG file so that I can rasterize it then send it to the printer. Emphasis on "parsing an SVG file"!!!

Comment: It looks like I'll have to figure it out on my own... I found vpype seems to do just what I need; I can load an SVG file, crop it to something reasonable, render it to a PIL image, than get a raster from that. I can't figure out how to get vpype to directly create a raster in an array so that I could bypass the PIL step.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works so far. It's very hackish, but for this project, I'm ok w/ it.

This is prototype code, not the real thing. It does show how to "chunk" a very large SVG file into pieces that a small printer can handle. For brevity, I'm just doing an img.show() instead of the reams of code to format it for the printer.

```
!/usr/bin/env python3

import copy
import vpype
import vpype_viewer

ifile = "VertWideExample.svg"

lcO, w, h = vpype.read_svg(ifile, quantization=.1, crop=True)

for I in range(0, 400, 100):
  print(I)
  lc = copy.copy(lcO)
  lc.crop(I, 0, I + 100, 13.2283536)
  v = vpype_viewer.ImageRenderer((640,480))
  doc = vpype.Document(lc)
  v.engine.document = doc
  v.engine.fit_to_viewport()
  img=v.render()
  img.show()
  V = None         # Segfaults w/o explicitly deleting
```